# How to save the SSMS Object Explorer servers?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio a lot. Every time I'm starting the tool, I'll need to connect to a server. Every day I'll need to connect to the same 4 servers. Is there a ways to "save" the servers in a file, so that I don't need to connect them every time I restart the tool.

It would be great if I could save some SQL scripts save into that file as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open "Registered Servers" from the "View" menu and persist them there?

Comment: Duh, I've been using SQL for 20 years and never knew this.  Thanks!